# Java Upside down and read words like

Tags: java

Question:
For all of the following words, if you move the first letter to the end of the word, and then spell the result backwards, you will get the original word:
Ex. banana dresser grammar potato revive uneven assess
Write a program that reads a word and determines whether it has this property. 
Continue reading and testing words until you encounter the word quit. 
Treat uppercase letters as lowercase letters.

```
   package homework;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Ex09 {
        public static void main(String args[]){
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            String arrInput[],input;
            String arrText[] = null,text,text_word,text_remain;
            int i;
            boolean check = true;

            while(true){
                //Type
                System.out.println("type string: ");
                input = keyboard.nextLine();
                input = input.toLowerCase();

                //If user type quit, terminate the program
                if(input.compareTo("quit")==0) break;

                arrInput = input.split(""); //by breaking the input should be kept in arrInput (the input array)

                //Send letters to the front to the back of the input (stored separately in the text)
                text_word = input.substring(0, 1); //the beginning of the input text to Back
                text_remain = input.substring(1, input.length()-1); //from the second to the last character of the input
                text = text_remain.concat(text_word); //merges into the text

                //break up the text should be kept in arrText (the text array)
                arrText = text.split("");

                //input (from the back) and text (from the front) to check for equality
                //Correct, check = true, incorrect, check = false
                for(i=0; i<input.length(); i++){
                    if(arrInput[i].equals(arrText[(input.length()-1)-i])){
                        check = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        check = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                //correct
                if(check){
                    System.out.println("equal");
                }
                //incorrect
                else{
                    System.out.println("Not equal");
                }
            }   
        }
    }
```

I can't see this code's problem.
But when I execute this code,

```
type string: 
banana
Not equal
type string: 
uneven
Not equal
type string:
```

What's the matter of this code?

Comment: You may be confused about the correct way to use `substring`.  Try reading the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-).

Comment: By the way, you don't actually have to create the string by moving the first letter to the end.  You could be clever and note that the problem is equivalent to asking, "if I drop the first letter, is the resulting substring a palindrome?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code The following is the corrected working code :

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {

            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            String arrInput[], input;
            String arrText[] = null, text, text_word, text_remain;
            int i;


            while (true) {
                // Type
                System.out.println("type string: ");
                input = keyboard.nextLine();
                input = input.toLowerCase();

                // If user type quit, terminate the program
                if (input.compareTo("quit") == 0)
                    break;

                arrInput = input.split(""); // by breaking the input should be kept
                                            // in arrInput (the input array)

                // Send letters to the front to the back of the input (stored
                // separately in the text)
                text_word = input.substring(0, 1); // the beginning of the input
                                                    // text to Back
                text_remain = input.substring(1, input.length()); // from the second
                                                                    // to the last
                                                                    // character of
                                                                    // the input
                text = text_remain.concat(text_word); // merges into the text
                System.out.println(text);
                // break up the text should be kept in arrText (the text array)


                // input (from the back) and text (from the front) to check for
                // equality
                // Correct, check = true, incorrect, check = false
                String original = text;
                String reverse = new String();
                int length = original.length();

                for (i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);

                if (input.equals(reverse))
                    System.out.println("equal");
                else 
                    System.out.println("Not equal");

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The following are the problems 1)You have misunderstood the use of String in java (you are using it like char[])  2) The following logic is wrong :   text_remain = input.substring(1, input.length()-1);

Comment: He's not using a `String` like a `char[]`.  Instead, he's using `split("")` to create a `String[]`, and using a `String[]` like a `char[]`.  Which is not the way I'd do it, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

I give you a simple example to solve your problem

```
  StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("banana");
        str.reverse();// ananab
        boolean val = true;
        for(int i = 0,j="banana".length()-1;i<"banana".length();i++,j--){
            if("banana".charAt(i)!=(str.charAt(j))){ // comparing str with banana in reverse order
                System.out.println("false");// if any of the char does not match 
                val = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(val==true){ // if all chars matched
            System.out.println("true");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

make

```
text_remain = input.substring(1, input.length()-1);
```

to

```
text_remain = input.substring(1, input.length());
```

or else your string will loose one character.
Eg: Banana --> ananB